# Can someone tell me what changed recently in this question?

Tags: support

This two year old question bumped to the top of my RSS feed.

[Include oracle in .net application deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368196/include-oracle-in-net-application-deployment)

Is this because of a hidden question getting edited which I cannot see since I don't have 10k or is it or some other factor?

Comment: It was like bumped, or "poked" by the *Community* User.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. Was it changed in some way? I see no edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that it was poked by the Community user as [Zizouz212](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4293417/zizouz212) said but it's more likely due to the answer that was given yesterday (then promptly deleted by a mod as a duplicate answer).

[image]

And, as you pointed out, you couldn't see this with less than 10k rep.

Comment: Oh well... You got it.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Your answer was a good guess since you couldn't see the deleted answer. And I still can't say for sure I'm right (not sure anyone can, even a mod) but just another (maybe more likely considering the timeline) possibility.

Comment: Just an answer popping up should've thrown it active, which likely sparked the movement. Aside from that, I can't see it being anything else from what we've said.

Comment: @Zizouz212 correct. It was most likely the answer posted (even though it was shortly after removed)

Comment: Thank you, codemagic. So it is spam that is messing up my RSS feed :)

Comment: @ChristianShay I don't know if I would call it spam. But a user maybe searching for similar questions to post a duplicate answer they gave on another question(s) for more rep which is not how this site is supposed to work. Hence, the moderator deletion and comment.

Comment: In this case, it was more or less spam since that answer has no relevance to the question except for the word "Oracle" :) Thanks again, and thanks to the hard work of the moderators to clean things up.

Comment: "More or less spam", but not spam according to what SO considers spam. Don't flag such as spam if you find it. Possibly use a custom flag though I expect mods have automated flags in these situations.

Answer (score -1):

Your question was likely bumped up by the [Community ♦ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). From the "user's" profile:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions

Comment: The scenario looks promising. Low views, no votes, no answers... A perfect place to be poked and brought back to the community's attention

Comment: Can someone verify this what actually happened? Someone with access to the change history. I really want to know.